# Dynamic Group Indicator for ExpandableList View

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How to set group indicator for ExpandableList View dynamically ?
I had group_indicator.xml in drawable folder.
But no idea of how to set it. Can anyone help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set **android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"** to your expandable list view in xml. Then you can set any indicator that you want to set. Suppose you have an image named "pin" in your drawable folder, then you need write following lines.

```
ExpandableListView explist;
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
explist.setGroupIndicator(d);
```

Thanks...

Comment: I'm not using this in onCreate method. I'm using outside, so how can I do it.

Comment: Once you define ExpandableListView object global, then you can use this from anywhere from your code. Put ExpandableListView explist; before your oncreate, and write these lines anywhere.

Comment: I'm using this outside the class which doesn't extends Activity

Comment: post your code where you need to use it, so I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have created **ExpandableListView** through code:

```
ExpandableListView ev = new ExpandableListView(this);
ev.setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group_indicator));
```